# Programs use byte streams to perform input and output of 8-bit byte

Tags: java

while reading about IO Streams in Java official source, I came across the following statements:

1) program uses an input stream to read data from a source, **one at a time**. What does it mean by the statement -> One at a time?

2) In byte stream as IO Stream, **Program Use byte streams to perform input and output of 8-bit byte** -- does it mean that, java processes one 8-bit (or a byte) of data at a time sequentially? Doesn't it include only the data that one intend to read or write OR it includes the instructions as well in the entire script?

Thank you!

Comment: Data is always transmitted one byte at a time, a byte has 8 bits in it.

Comment: Could you link to the "Java official source" you mention? I'd like to read what you quoted in context.

Comment: sure Stephen, here is the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html